# How To Access The Action Within Controller

Tags: php, yii, scope, yii-routing

I have a default controller named *`SiteController`* with some `actions` in it like:

```
-index
-aboutcompany
```

When I open my site in browser like: *localhost/lucky*

The *`index`* action is working properly.

On *index.php (view)* i made a link: `echo CHtml::link('About Company', array('site/aboutcompany));`

When I click on the link an error appears:

```
The requested url not found on this server.
```

None of the *actions (sitecontroller)* are working except *index*

Please suggest me the solution.

This is the controller code:

```
<?php

class SiteController extends Controller
{
public $layout='/layouts/main';

public function actions()
{
    return array(

        'captcha'=>array(
            'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
            'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
        ),


        'page'=>array(
            'class'=>'CViewAction',
        ),
    );
}


public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->render('index');
}

public function actionAboutCompany(){
    $this->render('aboutcompany');
    }
```

This is the config code

```
return array(
'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
'name'=>'My Web Application',

// preloading 'log' component
'preload'=>array('log'),

// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
),

'modules'=>array(

    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'test',
        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
    ),

),

// application components
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    ),

     'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'caseSensitive'=>false,  
       'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/list',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<title>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        ),

    ),
    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testyii',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),

    'errorHandler'=>array(
        // use 'site/error' action to display errors
        'errorAction'=>'site/error',
    ),
    'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),

            array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            ),

        ),
    ),
),
'params'=>array(
    'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
),
);
```

Comment: do you ve any htaccess?? I mean using any?

Comment: Yes, this is the content of my .htaccess
`Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>`

Comment: htaccess is gud.and hiding index.php?? show ur config main.php and SiteController also if u can. :)

Comment: `?php

class SiteController extends Controller
{
 public $layout='/layouts/main';
 
 public function actions()
 {
  return array(
   
   'captcha'=>array(
    'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
    'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
   ),
   'page'=>array(
    'class'=>'CViewAction',
   ),
  );
 }

 public function actionIndex()
 {
  $this->render('index');
 }

 public function actionAboutCompany(){
  $this->render('aboutcompany');
  }`

Comment: config file also and please update codes in ur question not in comment.

Comment: what is the url your getting while clicking the link?

Comment: I updated the question with controller code and main.php code

Comment: [link]http://localhost/lucky/site/aboutcompany

Comment: i think you should call `site/aboutCompany` not `aboutcompany`

Comment: your htcaccess file not replace index.php type your url with defining index.php in it

Comment: I think something is wrong with your .htaccess or mod-rewrite. Normally if it is an issue just with Yii finding the action you would get an error like this `The system is unable to find the requested action "aboutcompany".` Not a URL not found error. Can you confirm your htaccess and mod-rewrite are working?

Comment: Thanks Pitchinnate: I remove the `#` from the httpd.conf and restart the server and now every thing is working fine.